# Does Dead Space have many jumpscares?

Tags: dead-space

Does Dead Space have a lot of jumpscares?

Comment: I don't think we can really answer your question, because what's scary for one person isn't scary for another one. Yes, dead space has jumpscares but if you get scared by them, you'd have to play the game to find out.

Comment: I think his question can be answered though (we both just sort of did that, though).  It may not be scary, but there are indeed jump scares.

Comment: "Jumpscares ahoy" was the game's development title.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes the game has many "jump scares" depending on what you deduce as a jump scare

If you mean pretend dead bodies animating in front of you when you least expect it or things coming up behind you and you don't realize to the last second.

Then yes there is many.

The atmosphere overall is what makes this game scary, the jump scares just break that teeth grinding tension.

Comment: Note that if you're smart you can avoid most of the "thought it was dead" scares/dangers. When I see people thinking Necromorphs are dead but they really aren't, they've usually failed to remove both arms. You quickly get a feel for how much dismemberment should kill each enemy (and both arms is almost universally fatal).

Comment: There are also a few situations were things explode, doors suddenly slam shut in your face, or creatures dart around a corner as you walk through a door. All of these situations are harmless, unless you have a heart condition.

Answer (score 2):

OH YEAH! There are multiple jump scares set in the right places, but what is scary for people may not be scary for others. But there still are lots of jump scares. And they usually always work for unsuspecting players!